# When does Adria speak about "Suffering" and "The War's End" in Act 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I'm looking to hear Adria's dialogue on "Suffering" and "The War's End" but I can't seem to get her to want to talk about anything but Azmodan. She is in the armory with Leah working on the Black Soulstone and these two dialogue options are not available. Is there some other time in the Act to discuss this? Does she appear in a different location? Is it during a specific portion of a quest? I can't recall.

[image: Adria achievement]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These dialogues are only available during specific quests: **"Suffering" during "Turning the Tide" (Quest #2)**, and **"The War's End" during "Machines of War" (Quest #5)**, both in the **Armory** (southeast door in the Act III town).

[image: Suffering]
[image: The War's End]